# MongoDB $elemMatch of $elemMatch and good practice

Tags: mongodb

H,

I'm trying to update the version field in this object but I'm not able to make a query with 2 nested $match. So what I would like to do is get the record with file id 12 and version 1.

I would ask also if is it a good practice have more the one nested array in mongoDB (like this object)...

Query:

```
db.collection.find({"my_uuid":"434343"},{"item":{$elemMatch:{"file_id":12,"changes":{$elemMatch:{"version":1}}}}}).pretty()
```

Object:

```
{
  "my_uuid": "434343",
  "item": [
    {
      "file_id": 12,
      "no_of_versions" : 1,
      "changes": [
        {
          "version": 1,
          "commentIds": [
            4,
            5,
            7
          ]
        },
        {
          "version": 2,
          "commentIds": [
            10,
            11,
            15
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file_id": 234,
      "unseen_comments": 3,
      "no_of_versions" : 2,
      "changes": [
        {
          "version": 1,
          "commentIds": [
            100,
            110,
            150
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer, we don't know the context of your schema or querying, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire documents that satisfy the criteria returned in the result, then I think it's fine.  But if you want to limit the array contents of `item` and `changes` to just the matching elements, then it could be a problem.  That's because, you'll have to use the [`$ positional`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in the projection to limit the contents of the array and **only one such operator can appear in the projection**.  So, you'll not be able to limit the contents of multiple arrays within the document.